# Magnific Popup: How to add a custom close button inside a popup form?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I have a form that opens up on a popup and have added a custom `close button` next to a submit button.

This is a jQuery I am using for the close button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#close').click(function() {
        $.magnificPopup.close();
    });
});
```

However this does not seem to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Use `parent.$.magnificPopup.close();` if the magnificPopup type is `iframe`.

Answer (score 11):

If your snippet is located in your main js, the ajax popup button may not be binded to the event.
I imagine two solutions :

### Use "on" instead of "click" :(not tested)

```
$('#close').on( "click", function() {
  $.magnificPopup.close();
});
```

### Or do it that way : (tested)

**add this function in your main js**

```
function closePopup() {
  $.magnificPopup.close();
}
```

**And use this kind of button in your popup html**

```
<button type="button" onClick="closePopup();">Close</button>
```

**Iframe :**

If your button is located in an iframe and the magnificpopup script in the main window, **on the same domain**, you can access the above function like this :

```
<button type="button" onClick="parent.closePopup();">Close</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still does not work. When the button is clicked, `closePopup()` function gets called but `$.magnificPopup.close()` is not triggered. I am using an Ajax form in PHP but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: do you try to load an iframe in your popup ?

Comment: Yes I am using iframe.

Comment: Is there a solution without the need of an additional jQuery inline function `closePopup`? Something that only uses onClick

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
<pre class="default prettyprint prettyprinted">
<code>

    $('#close').click(function(){
        $('.mfp-close').trigger('click');
      });

</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: $('.mfp-close').trigger('click'); work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some of these answers work, but it depends on your implementation of the popup. If you're still having trouble, I'd suggest using the callback method to ensure consistency:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: $domElement,
    type: 'inline'
  }, 
  callbacks: {
    open: function() { 
        $('#close-btn').on('click',function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          $.magnificPopup.close();
        }); 
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add inside popup parameters `closeBtnInside:true`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug in magnific pop up. In order to use button inside container you have to supply fixedContentPos: true;

following code seems to work for me fine. Hope it helps.

```
    $('.ajax-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'ajax',
        removalDelay: 100, // Delay in milliseconds before popup is removed
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-slide-bottom',`enter code here` // Class that is added to popup wrapper and background
        closeOnContentClick: false, 
        closeOnBgClick: false,
        showCloseBtn: true,
        closeBtnInside: true,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        alignTop: true,
//        settings: {cache:false, async:false},
        callbacks: {
            open: function () {   
            },
            beforeClose: function () {
                this.content.addClass('light-speed-out');
            },
            close: function () {
                this.content.removeClass('light-speed-out');
            }
        },
        midClick: true

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$.magnificPopup.close();
.. would work if you put it in your content loaded with ajax

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Solution**

*Methods below don't have* shorthand like "open" and "close".

They should be called through "instance" object.
"instance" is available only when at least one popup was opened.
For example: **$.magnificPopup.instance.doSomething();**

here example of customized close for magnificPopup

// save magnificPopup instance in variable

```
var magnificPopup = $.magnificPopup.instance;
```

//open magnific instance

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: 'someimage.jpg'
  },
  type: 'image'
}, 0);
```

// Close popup that is currently opened

```
magnificPopup.close();
```

// Navigation when gallery is enabled

```
magnificPopup.next(); // go to next item
magnificPopup.prev(); // go to prev item
magnificPopup.goTo(4); // go to item #4
```

// updates the popup content. Useful after you change "items"

```
magnificPopup.updateItemHTML();
```

**2. Solution**

you can add a button within the popup and assign a function on click event like:

```
$('#close-button-verify').click(function(){
    //This will close the most recently popped dialog
    //This method specially works for auto popped dialogs i.e.
    //Popup you opened using $.magnificPopup.open()

    $.magnificPopup.close();
 });
```

If popup is triggered via onClick event then the same jQuery Object can be used to close that popup

```
$('#close-button-verify').click(function(){
    $('#id_of_button_that_opened_magnificpopup').magnificPopup('close');
 });
```

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add "mfp-close" class to your control, something like this:

```
    <a href="#" title="Close" type="button" class="btn btn-default mfp-close">Close</a>
```

Here Bootstrap classes also used to make link looks like button - doesn't matter.

Comment: This just adds a close div to the top right corner, not what has been asked here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
  type: 'inline'
});
 $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.magnificPopup.close();
 });
});

<div class="popup-modal mfp-hide">
 <h1>Modal</h1>
 <p>Modal Description.</p>
 <p><a class="popup-modal-dismiss mfp-close-btn-in" href="#">Close</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's already an existing answer in the Magnific Popup Doc.

It's :

```
$('.popup-link').magnificPopup({
     closeMarkup: '<button title="%title%" type="button" class="mfp-close"> {enter your custom markup here} </button>',
     tClose: 'Button title',
});
```